# Apply function to every pair of cells in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell array with 943 cells, each cell contains an array of binary elements. I want to apply a function (e.g. 'and' operation) on each pair of cells, for example:

```
and(cell1,cell2), and(cell1,cell3) ..... and(cell1,cell943)
                  and(cell2,cell3) ..... and(cell2,cell943)
.                                                 .
.                                                 .                                                  
.                                                 .
.                                        and(cell942,cell943)
```

For the efficiency purpose, i don't want to repeat the function on a same pair twice. How can i do this?

Comment: What does `and` even mean for cells?

Comment: @knedlsepp: A cell is the element of a cell array, I assume the cells contain some data which is a valid input for `and`

Comment: The answer depends on the cell contents and the function. In certain cases vectorization can be achieved. But you need to give those details

Comment: @Daniel: If the cells contain data which is valid input for `and`, OP should use `cell2mat`.

Comment: @knedlsepp: `cell2mat` requires uniform size inputs, `and` not. It also works with one scalar and one vector. But you are right, when they are uniform a fully vectorized solution should be considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a solution using a simple for loop:

```
A = { [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1] ;
      [1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1] ;
      [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1] }

n = numel(A);
combs = nchoosek(1:n,2)

for ii = 1:n
    output{ii,1} = A{combs(ii,1)} & A{combs(ii,2)};
    output{ii,2} = combs(ii,:);
end
```

---

returning:

[image]

In the first column you have the result of your operation and in the second column the rows involved (of the initial cell array).

---

Or use `arrayfun` instead of the loop:

```
output = arrayfun(@(x) A{combs(x,1)} & A{combs(x,2)},1:n,'uni',0).';
```